# Connect with SSH to a Cisco Switch through a Cisco Router

Tags: networking, ssh, cisco

Trying to ssh a switch from Putty through a Router that works when doing if I connect first to the router via console cable and when there I SSH the switch then it works but when trying to do it from putty it says Network error: connection timeout

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solutions. In windows Just went to the Inbounds rule for in Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security and then set inbounds and outbounds rules allowing TCP port and another rule for Allowing another subnet witch the one you want to SSH.
On Mac Using terminal type sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config then Un-comment the line: Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
Press Ctrl + X. Press Enter to save and exit.